# Creating grouped barplot in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R, that looks something  like this:

```
 Requirements   Documentation   Development  Delivery

 After          After           During       During
 Before         After           Before       After
 After          Before          Before       During
 During         During          After        Before
...
```

And I need to create a histogram that it has to look like the image below, but I can't create the right dataset

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

```
  df <- data.frame(
      Requirement = c("After", "Before", "After", "During"),
      Documentation = c("After", "After", "Before", "During"),
      Development = c("During", "Before", "Before", "After"),
      Delivery = c("During", "After", "During", "Before")
    )
```

You first have to reshape your dataframe in a long format

```
library(tidyr)
newdf <- gather(df)


p <- ggplot(data=newdf, aes(x=key, y=value, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())+
  theme_minimal()
p
```